How to bound a sum of absolute value of centered Randemacher variables
Consider
\begin{equation}
    A_{i}=\begin{cases}
      1,\text{ with probability } 1-p\\
       -1,\text{ with probability } p\\
    \end{cases}\,.
\end{equation}  and $p<1/2$.
What would be the upper bound of
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i}-2p+1|\leq \cdots$$ with high probability?
What I did is the following,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i}-2p+1|\leq\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i}|+|-2p+1|=\sum_{i=1}^n 1 + 1-2p=n\cdot (2-2p)$$
Would this be tight? Thank you in advance for any comment/answer!

Please give a reference for Randemacher random variables : I hadn't heard of them...

@JeanMarie Perhaps OP means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution

Oh, I see, orthographic problems ! I thought that Randmacher = maker of Rand was a pun for a very special unknown brand of random variables...

Let $\xi_i=|a_i-2p+1|$, then $\xi=2(1-p)$ with probability $1-p$ and $\xi=2p$ with probability $p$. Hence $\mathbb{E}(\xi_i)=2(1-p)\cdot(1-p)+2p\cdot p=(2p-1)^2+1=:\mu$ and $\xi_i$s are i.i.d. Now you can use  both law of large number and the CLT, so if $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n |A_i-2p+1|$, then
$$
\frac{S_n}n\to\mu\quad{a.s.};\quad \frac{S_n-\mu n}{\sqrt n}\to \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)
$$
with $\sigma^2=Var(\xi_i)$,
which gives you the required bbounds.
